# How to get content inside of divs using same js onclick event

Tags: javascript

I have 2 divs by class name tag which contain p,span tags . So when I trigger an onclick event on a div they should log or show the content of p, span tags.
But when I am doing that it gives all the content of say 2 divs that I have in my markup.

How do I go by that when I click on that particular div the content of p, span tags of that clicked div should be displayed and not of all the p, span tags.

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
var pTag = document.querySelectorAll("P");
var sTag = document.querySelectorAll("SPAN");
for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
  tag[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < pTag.length; j++) {
      console.log(pTag[j].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-1</p>
  <span>10</span>
</div>

<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-2</p>
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```

Comment: '*I have 2 divs by class name tag which contain*' - You mean class right? Class / name are both different properties, unless you mean the tag name?

Comment: yes class......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` should be inside `for` loop. Also to get the text you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`:

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
var pTag = document.querySelectorAll("P");
var sTag = document.querySelectorAll("SPAN");
for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < pTag.length; j++) {
    tag[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.textContent);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-1</p>
  <span>10</span>
</div>

<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-2</p>
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this will solve your issue

```js
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
var pTag = document.querySelectorAll("P");
var sTag = document.querySelectorAll("SPAN");
function showContent(event){
   console.log(event.lastElementChild.innerText);
}
```

```html
<div class="tag" onclick="showContent(this)">
  <p>Head Text-1</p>
  <span>10</span>
</div>

<div class="tag" onclick="showContent(this)">
  <p>Head Text-2</p>
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to get your tag's `textContent`, But instead, your `tag.onclick` show the entire document's `p` elements (which is your `pTag` in your question).

Following is a sample how you can select the children element's `p` and `span` of the clicked `.tag`

```js
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName("tag");
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
  tags[i].onclick = function () {
    var self = this,
      childParagraphs = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("p"), function(elem) {
        return elem.parentNode === self;
      }),
      childSpans = [].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("span"), function(elem) {
        return elem.parentNode === self;
      });

    for (var j = 0; j < childParagraphs.length; j++) {
      console.log('childParagraph: ', childParagraphs[j].innerHTML);
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < childSpans.length; j++) {
      console.log('childSpan: ', childSpans[j].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-1</p>
  <span>10</span>
</div>

<div class="tag">
  <p>Head Text-2</p>
  <span>20</span>
</div>
```

Or, if you really just need the whole text of the entire `.tag`, you can use @Mamun answer by using `textContent`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, would this be more advantageous over @Mamun answer or it's just an another way to receive the same output?

Comment: Depends on your purpose. If you just want to get the `text` inside your `.tag`, then I'd say @Mamun answer is more advantageous. But if you want to do more DOM manipulation within the children of `.tag`, then this is a way to go.